# SQL to XML Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I was hoping I could get some help with this last part of a somewhat complicated problem I have been working on.

We have to produce an XML file from a SQL table that we are generating.

At its core the XML needs three elements.
Patient
   PhoneAssessment
   F2FAssessment

This is working as I'll show in my test code. However, the one problem we have is that if someone has both a F2FAssessment and a PhoneAssessment it will generate multiple  tags.

If you all could give me some insight on the best way to fix this to where there will only be one Patient tag that contains all possible PhoneAssessment and F2FAssessment tags it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the SQL code:

```
 use tempdb;
    declare @t table
    (
        [people_id] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [actual_date] [date] NULL,
        [NPI] [int] NULL,
        [FileCreationDate] [date] NULL,
        [FileCreationTime] [time](7) NULL,
        [ProviderPatientNo] [int] NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [SSN] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [DOB] [date] NULL,
        [Gender] [int] NULL,
        [Race] [int] NULL,
        [Ethnicity] [int] NULL,
        [ProviderPhoneAssessmentId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [CallEndDate] [date] NULL,
        [CallEndTime] [time](7) NULL,
        [DispatchDate] [date] NULL,
        [DispatchTime] [time](7) NULL,
        [CallDisposition] [int] NULL,
        [DispositionOther] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [Notes] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [ProviderF2FAssessmentId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [AssessmentDate] [date] NULL,
        [ArrivalTime] [time](7) NULL,
        [ResidentialStatus] [int] NULL,
        [County] [int] NULL,
        [EmploymentStatus] [int] NULL,
        [MaritalStatus] [int] NULL,
        [MilitaryStatus] [int] NULL,
        [NumArrests30Days] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [AttendedSchoolLast3Months] [int] NULL,
        [EducationLevel] [int] NULL,
        [PrimaryPayorSource] [int] NULL,
        [SecondaryPayorSource] [int] NULL,
        [AnnualHouseholdIncome] [int] NULL,
        [NumberInHousehold] [int] NULL,
        [CurrentServices] [int] NULL,
        [MHTreatmentDeclaration] [int] NULL,
        [MOTStatus] [int] NULL,
        [DurablePOA] [int] NULL,
        [AssessmentLocation] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [TransportedByLE] [int] NULL,
        [TelevideoAssessment] [int] NULL,
        [CurrentDetoxSymptoms] [int] NULL,
        [HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms] [int] NULL,
        [PrimaryDSMDiagnosis] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [SecondaryDSMDiagnosis] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [CompletedByLastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [CompletedByFirstName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [DateDispositionCompleted] [date] NULL,
        [TimeDispositionCompleted] [time](7) NULL,
        [RecommendedTransportMode] [int] NULL,
        [DateTransportedToFacility] [date] NULL,
        [TimeTransportedToFacility] [time](7) NULL,
        [FollowupContacted] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [FollowupReportedServiceHelpful] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [ContactAttempts] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [IsAdmitted] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [FirstHospitalization] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [PrimaryProblem] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [IntellectualDisability] [int] NULL,
        [MedicalInstability] [int] NULL,
        [MedicationIssues] [int] NULL,
        [PastTrauma] [int] NULL,
        [SubstanceAbuse] [int] NULL,
        [Drug] [int] NULL,
        [DrugRoute] [int] NULL,
        [DrugFrequency] [int] NULL,
        [HospAlternative] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [HospAltDisposition] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [Hospitalization] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [HospitalizationDisposition] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [SCS_Stf_Recommend] [nvarchar](255) NULL
    )
    insert INTO @t
    ([people_id],[actual_date],[NPI],[FileCreationDate],[FileCreationTime],[ProviderPatientNo],[LastName],[FirstName],[SSN],[DOB],[Gender],[Race],[Ethnicity],[ProviderPhoneAssessmentId],[CallEndDate],[CallEndTime],[DispatchDate],[DispatchTime],[CallDisposition],[DispositionOther],[Notes],[ProviderF2FAssessmentId],[AssessmentDate],[ArrivalTime],[ResidentialStatus],[County],[EmploymentStatus],[MaritalStatus],[MilitaryStatus],[NumArrests30Days],[AttendedSchoolLast3Months],[EducationLevel],[PrimaryPayorSource],[SecondaryPayorSource],[AnnualHouseholdIncome],[NumberInHousehold],[CurrentServices],[MHTreatmentDeclaration],[MOTStatus],[DurablePOA],[AssessmentLocation],[TransportedByLE],[TelevideoAssessment],[CurrentDetoxSymptoms],[HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms],[PrimaryDSMDiagnosis],[SecondaryDSMDiagnosis],[CompletedByLastName],[CompletedByFirstName],[DateDispositionCompleted],[TimeDispositionCompleted],[RecommendedTransportMode],[DateTransportedToFacility],[TimeTransportedToFacility],[FollowupContacted],[FollowupReportedServiceHelpful],[ContactAttempts],[VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended],[AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth],[IsAdmitted],[FirstHospitalization],[PrimaryProblem],[IntellectualDisability],[MedicalInstability],[MedicationIssues],[PastTrauma],[SubstanceAbuse],[Drug],[DrugRoute],[DrugFrequency],[HospAlternative],[HospAltDisposition],[Hospitalization],[HospitalizationDisposition],[SCS_Stf_Recommend])
    VALUES
    ('90F07844-746A-4347-82CA-39D4332B43F3','2013-09-25','1306875695','2014-02-12','15:19:37.0000000','108677','David','Joe','414555555','1999-01-23','2','1','2','59DC25C9-B659-42A3-B43D-26C741F9B929','2013-09-26','15:17:00.0000000',NULL,NULL,'1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'87',NULL,'6','4',NULL,NULL,NULL,'9','9',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'LastName','Alisha','2013-09-26','15:17:00.0000000',NULL,NULL,NULL,'0',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'0',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
    ('90F07844-746A-4347-82CA-39D4332B43F3','2013-09-25','1306875695','2014-02-12','15:19:37.0000000','108677','David','Joe','414555555','1999-01-23','2','1','2',NULL,'2013-09-25','18:45:00.0000000','2013-09-25','18:51:00.0000000','4',NULL,NULL,'35159D47-32B2-445C-A905-019E191FDDE2','2013-09-25','19:22:00.0000000','13','47','12','6','4',NULL,'3','23','8','9','0','4','8','3','3','3','4','0','0','0','0','V71.09   ','V71.09','Tweed','A','2013-09-25','21:10:51.0000000','3',NULL,NULL,'1','1',NULL,'0','0','0',NULL,'2','3','3','3','3','2',NULL,NULL,NULL,'8','4',NULL,NULL,NULL)

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Patient') IS NOT NULL drop table #Patient
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Drugs') IS NOT NULL drop table #Drugs
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Assessments') IS NOT NULL drop table #Assessments
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#HospAlt') IS NOT NULL drop table #HospAlt
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#HospDisp') IS NOT NULL drop table #HospDisp
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#PatientDistinct') IS NOT NULL drop table #PatientDistinct

    --Patient Distinct
    select distinct
    ProviderPatientNo
    into #PatientDistinct
    FROM @t


    --Patients
    select distinct
    NPI,
    FileCreationDate,
    FileCreationTime,
    ProviderPatientNo,
    ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
    ProviderPhoneAssessmentId,
    people_id, LastName,FirstName,
    SSN,[DOB],[Gender],[Race],[Ethnicity]
    into #Patient
    FROM @t

    --Assessments
    SELECT
    CallEndDate,
    CallEndTime,
    DispatchDate,
    DispatchTime,
    CallDisposition,
    DispositionOther,
    Notes,
    people_id,
    ProviderPatientNo,
    ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
    ProviderPhoneAssessmentId,
    AssessmentDate, 
    case when ArrivalTime is null then '07:00:00' else ArrivalTime end AS [ArrivalTime] ,
    ResidentialStatus AS [ResidentialStatus],
    County AS [County], 
    EmploymentStatus AS [EmploymentStatus], 
    MaritalStatus AS [MaritalStatus], 
    MilitaryStatus AS [MilitaryStatus],
    NumArrests30Days AS [NumArrests30Days], 
    AttendedSchoolLast3Months AS [AttendedSchoolLast3Months], 
    EducationLevel AS [EducationLevel], 
    PrimaryPayorSource AS [PrimaryPayorSource], 
    SecondaryPayorSource AS [SecondaryPayorSource], 
    AnnualHouseholdIncome AS [AnnualHouseholdIncome],
    NumberInHousehold AS [NumberInHousehold], 
    CurrentServices AS [CurrentServices], 
    MHTreatmentDeclaration AS [MHTreatmentDeclaration], 
    MOTStatus AS [MOTStatus], 
    DurablePOA AS [DurablePOA], 
    AssessmentLocation AS [AssessmentLocation], 
    TransportedByLE AS [TransportedByLE], 
    TelevideoAssessment AS [TelevideoAssessment],
    CurrentDetoxSymptoms AS [CurrentDetoxSymptoms], 
    HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms AS [HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms],
    PrimaryDSMDiagnosis AS [PrimaryDSMDiagnosis], 
    SecondaryDSMDiagnosis AS [SecondaryDSMDiagnosis],
    CompletedByLastName AS [CompletedByLastName], 
    CompletedByFirstName AS [CompletedByFirstName],
    DateDispositionCompleted AS [DateDispositionCompleted], 
    TimeDispositionCompleted AS [TimeDispositionCompleted], 
    RecommendedTransportMode AS [RecommendedTransportMode], 
    DateTransportedToFacility AS [DateTransportedToFacility], 
    TimeTransportedToFacility AS [TimeTransportedToFacility], 
    FollowupContacted AS [FollowupContacted],
    FollowupReportedServiceHelpful AS [FollowupReportedServiceHelpful], 
    ContactAttempts AS [ContactAttempts], 
    VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended AS [VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended], 
    AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth AS [AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth], 
    IsAdmitted AS [IsAdmitted], 
    FirstHospitalization AS [FirstHospitalization],
    PrimaryProblem AS [PrimaryProblem], 
    IntellectualDisability AS [IntellectualDisability], 
    MedicalInstability AS [MedicalInstability], 
    MedicationIssues AS [MedicationIssues], 
    PastTrauma AS [PastTrauma], 
    SubstanceAbuse AS [SubstanceAbuse]
    into #Assessments
    FROM @t

    --Drugs
    select ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
    Drug,
    DrugRoute,
    DrugFrequency
    into #Drugs
    from @t
    where ProviderF2FAssessmentId is not null

    --HospAlternative
    select 
    ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
    HospAlternative,
    HospAltDisposition
    into #HospAlt
    from @t
    where ProviderF2FAssessmentId is not null

    --Hospitalization
    select
    ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
    1 as Hospitalization,
    10 as HospitalizationDisposition
    into #HospDisp
    from @t
    where ProviderF2FAssessmentId is not null



    /*Create XML*/
    declare @output XML

    set @output =
    --Provider Data
    (
    SELECT  
    NPI as [NPI], 
    FileCreationDate as [FileCreationDate], 
    cast(FileCreationTime as time) FileCreationTime,
    (
    --Patient Data

    Select  
    Patient.ProviderPatientNo ,
    LastName as [LastName],
    FirstName as [FirstName],
    SSN as [SSN],
    DOB as [DOB],
    Gender as [Gender],
    Race as [Race],
    Ethnicity as [Ethnicity],      
           --Phone Assessment Data
           /*
           <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>52854541</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
           <CallEndDate>2006-05-04</CallEndDate>
           <CallEndTime>01:01:01.001</CallEndTime>
           <DispatchDate>2006-05-04</DispatchDate>
           <DispatchTime>01:01:01.001</DispatchTime>
           <CallDisposition>1</CallDisposition>
           <DispositionOther>DispositionOther0</DispositionOther>
           <Notes>Notes0</Notes>
           */
           (
           Select  
           ProviderPhoneAssessmentId,
           CallEndDate,
           CallEndTime,
           DispatchDate,
           DispatchTime,
           CallDisposition,
           DispositionOther,
           Notes
           FROM #Assessments
           WHERE ProviderPhoneAssessmentId is NOT NULL and ProviderPhoneAssessmentId = Patient.ProviderPhoneAssessmentId
           FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, type) AS [PhoneAssessment/*],
              --F2FAssessment
              /*
              <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>4343</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
              <AssessmentDate>2006-05-04</AssessmentDate>
              <ArrivalTime>01:01:01.001</ArrivalTime>
              <ResidentialStatus>1</ResidentialStatus>
              <County>1</County>
              <EmploymentStatus>1</EmploymentStatus>
              <MaritalStatus>1</MaritalStatus>
              <MilitaryStatus>1</MilitaryStatus>
              <NumArrests30Days>50</NumArrests30Days>
              <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>1</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
              <EducationLevel>1</EducationLevel>
              <PrimaryPayorSource>1</PrimaryPayorSource>
              <SecondaryPayorSource>1</SecondaryPayorSource>
              <AnnualHouseholdIncome>0</AnnualHouseholdIncome>
              <NumberInHousehold>128</NumberInHousehold>
              <CurrentServices>1</CurrentServices>
              <MHTreatmentDeclaration>1</MHTreatmentDeclaration>
              <MOTStatus>1</MOTStatus>
              <DurablePOA>1</DurablePOA>
              <AssessmentLocation>1</AssessmentLocation>
              <TransportedByLE>false</TransportedByLE>
              <TelevideoAssessment>false</TelevideoAssessment>
              <CurrentDetoxSymptoms>false</CurrentDetoxSymptoms>
              <HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>false</HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>
              <PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>PrimaryDS</PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>
              <SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>Secondary</SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>
              <CompletedByLastName>CompletedByLastName2</CompletedByLastName>
              <CompletedByFirstName>CompletedByFirstName2</CompletedByFirstName>
              <DateDispositionCompleted>2006-05-04</DateDispositionCompleted>
              <TimeDispositionCompleted>01:01:01.001</TimeDispositionCompleted>
              <RecommendedTransportMode>1</RecommendedTransportMode>
              <DateTransportedToFacility>2006-05-04</DateTransportedToFacility>
              <TimeTransportedToFacility>01:01:01.001</TimeTransportedToFacility>
              <FollowupContacted>false</FollowupContacted>
              <FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>false</FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>
              <ContactAttempts>128</ContactAttempts>
              <VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>false</VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>
              <AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>false</AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>
              <IsAdmitted>false</IsAdmitted><FirstHospitalization>1</FirstHospitalization>
              <PrimaryProblem>1</PrimaryProblem><IntellectualDisability>1</IntellectualDisability>
              <MedicalInstability>1</MedicalInstability>
              <MedicationIssues>1</MedicationIssues>
              <PastTrauma>1</PastTrauma>
              <SubstanceAbuse>1</SubstanceAbuse>
              */
              (SELECT 
              ProviderF2FAssessmentId as [F2FAssessment/ProviderF2FAssessmentId],
              AssessmentDate as [F2FAssessment/AssessmentDate],
              [ArrivalTime]  as [F2FAssessment/ArrivalTime],
              ResidentialStatus  as [F2FAssessment/ResidentialStatus],
              County  as [F2FAssessment/County], 
              EmploymentStatus AS [F2FAssessment/EmploymentStatus], 
              MaritalStatus AS [F2FAssessment/MaritalStatus], 
              MilitaryStatus AS [F2FAssessment/MilitaryStatus],
              NumArrests30Days AS [F2FAssessment/NumArrests30Days], 
              AttendedSchoolLast3Months AS [F2FAssessment/AttendedSchoolLast3Months],
              EducationLevel AS [F2FAssessment/EducationLevel], 
              PrimaryPayorSource AS [F2FAssessment/PrimaryPayorSource], 
              SecondaryPayorSource AS [F2FAssessment/SecondaryPayorSource], 
              AnnualHouseholdIncome AS [F2FAssessment/AnnualHouseholdIncome],
              NumberInHousehold AS [F2FAssessment/NumberInHousehold], 
              CurrentServices AS [F2FAssessment/CurrentServices], 
              MHTreatmentDeclaration AS [F2FAssessment/MHTreatmentDeclaration], 
              MOTStatus AS [F2FAssessment/MOTStatus], 
              DurablePOA AS [F2FAssessment/DurablePOA], 
              AssessmentLocation AS [F2FAssessment/AssessmentLocation], 
              TransportedByLE AS [F2FAssessment/TransportedByLE], 
              TelevideoAssessment AS [F2FAssessment/TelevideoAssessment],
              CurrentDetoxSymptoms AS [F2FAssessment/CurrentDetoxSymptoms], 
              HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms AS [F2FAssessment/HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms],
              PrimaryDSMDiagnosis AS [F2FAssessment/PrimaryDSMDiagnosis], 
              SecondaryDSMDiagnosis AS [F2FAssessment/SecondaryDSMDiagnosis],
              CompletedByLastName AS [F2FAssessment/CompletedByLastName], 
              CompletedByFirstName AS [F2FAssessment/CompletedByFirstName],
              DateDispositionCompleted AS [F2FAssessment/DateDispositionCompleted], 
              TimeDispositionCompleted AS [F2FAssessment/TimeDispositionCompleted], 
              RecommendedTransportMode AS [F2FAssessment/RecommendedTransportMode], 
              ISNULL(CAST(DateTransportedToFacility as varchar(30)),'xsi:nil="true"') AS [F2FAssessment/DateTransportedToFacility], 
              ISNULL(CAST(TimeTransportedToFacility as varchar(30)),'xsi:nil="true"')AS [F2FAssessment/TimeTransportedToFacility], 
              FollowupContacted AS [F2FAssessment/FollowupContacted],
              FollowupReportedServiceHelpful AS [F2FAssessment/FollowupReportedServiceHelpful], 
              ContactAttempts AS [F2FAssessment/ContactAttempts], 
              VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended AS [F2FAssessment/VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended], 
              AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth AS [F2FAssessment/AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth], 
              IsAdmitted AS [F2FAssessment/IsAdmitted], 
              FirstHospitalization AS [F2FAssessment/FirstHospitalization],
              PrimaryProblem AS [F2FAssessment/PrimaryProblem], 
              IntellectualDisability AS [F2FAssessment/IntellectualDisability], 
              MedicalInstability AS [F2FAssessment/MedicalInstability], 
              MedicationIssues AS [F2FAssessment/MedicationIssues], 
              PastTrauma AS [F2FAssessment/PastTrauma], 
              SubstanceAbuse AS [F2FAssessment/SubstanceAbuse]
              ,
                 ( 
                        SELECT 
                        ISNULL(Drug,'') as Drug,
                        DrugRoute,
                        DrugFrequency
                        From #Drugs drugs
                        Where drugs.Drug is NOT NULL and drugs.ProviderF2FAssessmentId = #Assessments.ProviderF2FAssessmentId
                        FOR XML PATH(''), type) AS [F2FAssessment/F2FDrug] 
                    ,
                    ( 
                        SELECT 
                        HospAlternative,
                        HospAltDisposition
                        From #HospAlt HospAlt
                        Where HospAlt.ProviderF2FAssessmentId = #Assessments.ProviderF2FAssessmentId
                        FOR XML PATH(''), type) AS [F2FAssessment/F2FHospAlternative] 
                    ,
                    ( 
                        SELECT 
                        Hospitalization,
                        HospitalizationDisposition
                        From #HospDisp HospDisp
                        Where HospDisp.ProviderF2FAssessmentId = #Assessments.ProviderF2FAssessmentId
                        FOR XML PATH(''), type) AS [F2FAssessment/F2FHospitalization] 
              FROM #Assessments               
              Where ProviderF2FAssessmentId IS NOT NULL and ProviderF2FAssessmentId = Patient.ProviderF2FAssessmentId
              FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, type) AS [*] 

    FROM #Patient Patient 

    FOR XML PATH('Patient'), type
    )
    from @t
    group by NPI,FileCreationDate, FileCreationTime
    for xml path('')
    )

    ; with xmlnamespaces ('http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment' AS "xsd", 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi")
    select @output FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE, ROOT('Provider')
```

Here is an example of the XML output that I am currently getting:

```
    <Provider xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment">
      <NPI>1306875695</NPI>
      <FileCreationDate>2014-02-12</FileCreationDate>
      <FileCreationTime>15:19:37</FileCreationTime>
      <Patient>
        <ProviderPatientNo>108677</ProviderPatientNo>
        <LastName>David</LastName>
        <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
        <SSN>414555555</SSN>
        <DOB>1999-01-23</DOB>
        <Gender>2</Gender>
        <Race>1</Race>
        <Ethnicity>2</Ethnicity>
        <PhoneAssessment>
          <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>59DC25C9-B659-42A3-B43D-26C741F9B929</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
          <CallEndDate>2013-09-26</CallEndDate>
          <CallEndTime>15:17:00</CallEndTime>
          <CallDisposition>1</CallDisposition>
        </PhoneAssessment>
      </Patient>
      <Patient>
        <ProviderPatientNo>108677</ProviderPatientNo>
        <LastName>David</LastName>
        <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
        <SSN>414555555</SSN>
        <DOB>1999-01-23</DOB>
        <Gender>2</Gender>
        <Race>1</Race>
        <Ethnicity>2</Ethnicity>
        <F2FAssessment>
          <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>35159D47-32B2-445C-A905-019E191FDDE2</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
          <AssessmentDate>2013-09-25</AssessmentDate>
          <ArrivalTime>19:22:00</ArrivalTime>
          <ResidentialStatus>13</ResidentialStatus>
          <County>47</County>
          <EmploymentStatus>12</EmploymentStatus>
          <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
          <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
          <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>3</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
          <EducationLevel>23</EducationLevel>
          <PrimaryPayorSource>8</PrimaryPayorSource>
          <SecondaryPayorSource>9</SecondaryPayorSource>
          <AnnualHouseholdIncome>0</AnnualHouseholdIncome>
          <NumberInHousehold>4</NumberInHousehold>
          <CurrentServices>8</CurrentServices>
          <MHTreatmentDeclaration>3</MHTreatmentDeclaration>
          <MOTStatus>3</MOTStatus>
          <DurablePOA>3</DurablePOA>
          <AssessmentLocation>4</AssessmentLocation>
          <TransportedByLE>0</TransportedByLE>
          <TelevideoAssessment>0</TelevideoAssessment>
          <CurrentDetoxSymptoms>0</CurrentDetoxSymptoms>
          <HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>0</HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>
          <PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>V71.09   </PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>
          <SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>V71.09</SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>
          <CompletedByLastName>Tweed</CompletedByLastName>
          <CompletedByFirstName>A</CompletedByFirstName>
          <DateDispositionCompleted>2013-09-25</DateDispositionCompleted>
          <TimeDispositionCompleted>21:10:51</TimeDispositionCompleted>
          <RecommendedTransportMode>3</RecommendedTransportMode>
          <DateTransportedToFacility>xsi:nil="true"</DateTransportedToFacility>
          <TimeTransportedToFacility>xsi:nil="true"</TimeTransportedToFacility>
          <FollowupContacted>1</FollowupContacted>
          <FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>1</FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>
          <VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>0</VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>
          <AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>0</AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>
          <IsAdmitted>0</IsAdmitted>
          <PrimaryProblem>2</PrimaryProblem>
          <IntellectualDisability>3</IntellectualDisability>
          <MedicalInstability>3</MedicalInstability>
          <MedicationIssues>3</MedicationIssues>
          <PastTrauma>3</PastTrauma>
          <SubstanceAbuse>2</SubstanceAbuse>
          <F2FHospAlternative>
            <HospAlternative>8</HospAlternative>
            <HospAltDisposition>4</HospAltDisposition>
          </F2FHospAlternative>
          <F2FHospitalization>
            <Hospitalization>1</Hospitalization>
            <HospitalizationDisposition>10</HospitalizationDisposition>
          </F2FHospitalization>
        </F2FAssessment>
      </Patient>
    </Provider>
```

Here is an example of how I need it to look:

```
<Provider xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment">
  <NPI>1306875695</NPI>
  <FileCreationDate>2014-02-12</FileCreationDate>
  <FileCreationTime>15:19:37</FileCreationTime>
  <Patient>
    <ProviderPatientNo>108677</ProviderPatientNo>
    <LastName>David</LastName>
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
    <SSN>414555555</SSN>
    <DOB>1999-01-23</DOB>
    <Gender>2</Gender>
    <Race>1</Race>
    <Ethnicity>2</Ethnicity>
    <PhoneAssessment>
      <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>59DC25C9-B659-42A3-B43D-26C741F9B929</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
      <CallEndDate>2013-09-26</CallEndDate>
      <CallEndTime>15:17:00</CallEndTime>
      <CallDisposition>1</CallDisposition>
    </PhoneAssessment>
    <F2FAssessment>
      <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>35159D47-32B2-445C-A905-019E191FDDE2</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
      <AssessmentDate>2013-09-25</AssessmentDate>
      <ArrivalTime>19:22:00</ArrivalTime>
      <ResidentialStatus>13</ResidentialStatus>
      <County>47</County>
      <EmploymentStatus>12</EmploymentStatus>
      <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
      <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
      <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>3</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      <EducationLevel>23</EducationLevel>
      <PrimaryPayorSource>8</PrimaryPayorSource>
      <SecondaryPayorSource>9</SecondaryPayorSource>
      <AnnualHouseholdIncome>0</AnnualHouseholdIncome>
      <NumberInHousehold>4</NumberInHousehold>
      <CurrentServices>8</CurrentServices>
      <MHTreatmentDeclaration>3</MHTreatmentDeclaration>
      <MOTStatus>3</MOTStatus>
      <DurablePOA>3</DurablePOA>
      <AssessmentLocation>4</AssessmentLocation>
      <TransportedByLE>0</TransportedByLE>
      <TelevideoAssessment>0</TelevideoAssessment>
      <CurrentDetoxSymptoms>0</CurrentDetoxSymptoms>
      <HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>0</HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>
      <PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>V71.09   </PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>
      <SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>V71.09</SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>
      <CompletedByLastName>Tweed</CompletedByLastName>
      <CompletedByFirstName>A</CompletedByFirstName>
      <DateDispositionCompleted>2013-09-25</DateDispositionCompleted>
      <TimeDispositionCompleted>21:10:51</TimeDispositionCompleted>
      <RecommendedTransportMode>3</RecommendedTransportMode>
      <DateTransportedToFacility>xsi:nil="true"</DateTransportedToFacility>
      <TimeTransportedToFacility>xsi:nil="true"</TimeTransportedToFacility>
      <FollowupContacted>1</FollowupContacted>
      <FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>1</FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>
      <VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>0</VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>
      <AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>0</AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>
      <IsAdmitted>0</IsAdmitted>
      <PrimaryProblem>2</PrimaryProblem>
      <IntellectualDisability>3</IntellectualDisability>
      <MedicalInstability>3</MedicalInstability>
      <MedicationIssues>3</MedicationIssues>
      <PastTrauma>3</PastTrauma>
      <SubstanceAbuse>2</SubstanceAbuse>
      <F2FHospAlternative>
        <HospAlternative>8</HospAlternative>
        <HospAltDisposition>4</HospAltDisposition>
      </F2FHospAlternative>
      <F2FHospitalization>
        <Hospitalization>1</Hospitalization>
        <HospitalizationDisposition>10</HospitalizationDisposition>
      </F2FHospitalization>
    </F2FAssessment>
  </Patient>
</Provider>
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is working as I'll show in my test code. However, the one problem we have is that if someone has both a F2FAssessment and a PhoneAssessment it will generate multiple tags.*

This happen because you insert the person record 2 times.
first insert: Person data + phoneAssesment data
second insert: Peson data + F2FAssessment

Table t has 2 records for person with NPI:1306875695

my suggestion is to modify the @t table,

1. Create @temp1 table, the @temp1 should only have person data + phoneAssesment
2. Create @temp2 table, the @temp2 only contain PersonID + F2FAssessment (PErsonId act as foreign key)
3. Insert the data, to both table.
4. Inner Join both table @temp1 and @temp2 as Table @t. Use the PersonId as the join condition.
5. Now table @t will have only 1 record for NPI: 1306875695

Try this suggestion, Hope this is help.

Comment: That worked. Thank you for clearing up that mental road block for me.

Comment: While this does work to solve the problem with the assessments, it creates a new problem because sometimes I can have multiple PhoneAssessments but each one of those needs to exist under their own separate elements. Currently each phoneassessment exists under one phoneasessment when it should generate multiple entires. This may not be reflected in the test data I posted. Hope that makes sense, any advice you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: so a person can have multiple PhoneAssessment. You will need to separate the PersonData and PhoneAssessment and connect them with a foreign key (personId). If you are using a programming language then it will become a bit easier, you need a looping process to create the xml structure. But if you do not use any programming language you need to dig information about For XML Explicit (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one Patient element, make the `PhoneAssessment` and `F2F*` statements sub queries:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment')
SELECT 
    [NPI],
    [FileCreationDate],
    [FileCreationTime],
    (
        SELECT 
            ProviderPatientNo,
            LastName, FirstName,
            SSN, DOB, Gender,
            Race, Ethnicity,
            (
                SELECT 
                    ProviderPhoneAssessmentId, CallEndDate, CallEndTime, CallDisposition
                FROM @t pa
                WHERE ProviderPhoneAssessmentId is not null
                    and pa.ProviderPatientNo = p.ProviderPatientNo
                FOR XML PATH('PhoneAssesment'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL
            ),
            (
                SELECT 
                    ProviderF2FAssessmentId, 
                    AssessmentDate, ArrivalTime, ResidentialStatus, County, EmploymentStatus, 
                    MaritalStatus, MilitaryStatus, AttendedSchoolLast3Months, EducationLevel, 
                    PrimaryPayorSource, SecondaryPayorSource, AnnualHouseholdIncome, 
                    NumberInHousehold, CurrentServices, MHTreatmentDeclaration, MOTStatus, 
                    DurablePOA, AssessmentLocation, TransportedByLE, TelevideoAssessment, 
                    CurrentDetoxSymptoms, HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms, PrimaryDSMDiagnosis, 
                    SecondaryDSMDiagnosis, CompletedByLastName, CompletedByFirstName, 
                    DateDispositionCompleted, TimeDispositionCompleted, RecommendedTransportMode, 
                    DateTransportedToFacility, TimeTransportedToFacility, FollowupContacted, 
                    FollowupReportedServiceHelpful, VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended, 
                    AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth, IsAdmitted, PrimaryProblem, 
                    IntellectualDisability, MedicalInstability, MedicationIssues, PastTrauma, 
                    SubstanceAbuse,
                    HospAlternative as [F2FHospAlternative/HospAlternative],
                    HospAltDisposition as [F2FHospAlternative/HospAltDisposition],
                    Hospitalization as [F2FHospitalization/Hospitalization],
                    HospitalizationDisposition as [F2FHospitalization/HospitalizationDisposition]
                FROM @t f2f
                WHERE f2f.ProviderF2FAssessmentId is not null 
                    and f2f.ProviderPatientNo = p.ProviderPatientNo
                GROUP BY ProviderF2FAssessmentId, 
                    AssessmentDate, ArrivalTime, ResidentialStatus, County, EmploymentStatus, 
                    MaritalStatus, MilitaryStatus, AttendedSchoolLast3Months, EducationLevel, 
                    PrimaryPayorSource, SecondaryPayorSource, AnnualHouseholdIncome, 
                    NumberInHousehold, CurrentServices, MHTreatmentDeclaration, MOTStatus, 
                    DurablePOA, AssessmentLocation, TransportedByLE, TelevideoAssessment, 
                    CurrentDetoxSymptoms, HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms, PrimaryDSMDiagnosis, 
                    SecondaryDSMDiagnosis, CompletedByLastName, CompletedByFirstName, 
                    DateDispositionCompleted, TimeDispositionCompleted, RecommendedTransportMode, 
                    DateTransportedToFacility, TimeTransportedToFacility, FollowupContacted, 
                    FollowupReportedServiceHelpful, VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended, 
                    AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth, IsAdmitted, PrimaryProblem, 
                    IntellectualDisability, MedicalInstability, MedicationIssues, PastTrauma, 
                    SubstanceAbuse, HospAlternative, HospAltDisposition, Hospitalization,
                    HospitalizationDisposition
                FOR XML PATH('F2FAssessment'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL
            )
        FROM @t p
        GROUP BY ProviderPatientNo, LastName, FirstName, SSN, DOB, Gender, Race, Ethnicity
        FOR XML PATH('Patient'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL
    )
FROM (SELECT TOP(1) [NPI], [FileCreationDate], [FileCreationTime] FROM @t) as FileHeader
FOR XML PATH('Provider'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

Also, I am guessing you want `xsi:nil="true"` to be an attribute.  That is achieved through the [`XSINIL` option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178079.aspx).  Also, you reference a namespace, but do not use it.  Do you mean to make it the default (`WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment')`)?

Produces:

```
<Provider xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment">
  <NPI>1306875695</NPI>
  <FileCreationDate>2014-02-12</FileCreationDate>
  <FileCreationTime>15:19:37</FileCreationTime>
  <Patient xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment">
    <ProviderPatientNo>108677</ProviderPatientNo>
    <LastName>David</LastName>
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
    <SSN>414555555</SSN>
    <DOB>1999-01-23</DOB>
    <Gender>2</Gender>
    <Race>1</Race>
    <Ethnicity>2</Ethnicity>
    <PhoneAssesment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment">
      <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>59DC25C9-B659-42A3-B43D-26C741F9B929</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
      <CallEndDate>2013-09-26</CallEndDate>
      <CallEndTime>15:17:00</CallEndTime>
      <CallDisposition>1</CallDisposition>
    </PhoneAssesment>
    <F2FAssessment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.tn.gov/mental/Schemas/CrisisAssessment">
      <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>35159D47-32B2-445C-A905-019E191FDDE2</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
      <AssessmentDate>2013-09-25</AssessmentDate>
      <ArrivalTime>19:22:00</ArrivalTime>
      <ResidentialStatus>13</ResidentialStatus>
      <County>47</County>
      <EmploymentStatus>12</EmploymentStatus>
      <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
      <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
      <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>3</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      <EducationLevel>23</EducationLevel>
      <PrimaryPayorSource>8</PrimaryPayorSource>
      <SecondaryPayorSource>9</SecondaryPayorSource>
      <AnnualHouseholdIncome>0</AnnualHouseholdIncome>
      <NumberInHousehold>4</NumberInHousehold>
      <CurrentServices>8</CurrentServices>
      <MHTreatmentDeclaration>3</MHTreatmentDeclaration>
      <MOTStatus>3</MOTStatus>
      <DurablePOA>3</DurablePOA>
      <AssessmentLocation>4</AssessmentLocation>
      <TransportedByLE>0</TransportedByLE>
      <TelevideoAssessment>0</TelevideoAssessment>
      <CurrentDetoxSymptoms>0</CurrentDetoxSymptoms>
      <HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>0</HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms>
      <PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>V71.09   </PrimaryDSMDiagnosis>
      <SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>V71.09</SecondaryDSMDiagnosis>
      <CompletedByLastName>Tweed</CompletedByLastName>
      <CompletedByFirstName>A</CompletedByFirstName>
      <DateDispositionCompleted>2013-09-25</DateDispositionCompleted>
      <TimeDispositionCompleted>21:10:51</TimeDispositionCompleted>
      <RecommendedTransportMode>3</RecommendedTransportMode>
      <DateTransportedToFacility xsi:nil="true" />
      <TimeTransportedToFacility xsi:nil="true" />
      <FollowupContacted>1</FollowupContacted>
      <FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>1</FollowupReportedServiceHelpful>
      <VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>0</VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended>
      <AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>0</AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth>
      <IsAdmitted>0</IsAdmitted>
      <PrimaryProblem>2</PrimaryProblem>
      <IntellectualDisability>3</IntellectualDisability>
      <MedicalInstability>3</MedicalInstability>
      <MedicationIssues>3</MedicationIssues>
      <PastTrauma>3</PastTrauma>
      <SubstanceAbuse>2</SubstanceAbuse>
      <F2FHospAlternative>
        <HospAlternative>8</HospAlternative>
        <HospAltDisposition>4</HospAltDisposition>
      </F2FHospAlternative>
      <F2FHospitalization>
        <Hospitalization xsi:nil="true" />
        <HospitalizationDisposition xsi:nil="true" />
      </F2FHospitalization>
    </F2FAssessment>
  </Patient>
</Provider>
```

Comment: This is really close however it leaves out the F2FDrug elements.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how to add the provider tag back in correctly to make it the root. If you could elaborate on that it would be very helpful.

Comment: @user1441145, my intent was to demonstrate how to do it, not to do it for you.  The example I gave includes sub-queries, you can add as many as needed to produce the elements you are looking for.

Comment: @user1441145, There is no difference between a single element and a root element.  Unless you have more than one provider element, that is your root.  You are just producing it as the result of a row.

Comment: I appreciate the input, I'm not asking you to do it for me. However, for the Drug(F2FDrug) it needs to exist under the F2FAssessment. So I have added that back in. My question would be how do I avoid returning xsinil for some values in the f2f assessment but return it for others that are specified in the schema?

Comment: I see what you're saying... That seems to have fixed it now. Thank you so much.